# Topological invariance of compactly supported de Rham cohomology

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms, de-rham-cohomology

It is well-known that if we are given two smooth manifolds (without) boundary, whose underlying topological spaces are homotopic, then the de Rham cohomologies $H^k_{dR}$ of $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic for all $k\geq 0$ [See Theorem 17.11 in Lee's smooth manifolds book]. I was wondering if a similar result holds for the compactly supported de Rham cohomologies $H^k_c(M)$ and $H^k_c(N)$. I know that such a result doesn't hold if we only demand a standard homotopy relation. However Lee mentions shortly in his book that proper smooth maps induce maps between the compactly supported groups. In Exercise 6-8 of Lee's book
 we are asked to show that every proper continuous map is homotopic to a proper smooth map, but I'm not sure if the homotopy is in fact proper, which according to this thread [Invariance of de Rham cohomology with compact support](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/291598/invariance-of-de-rham-cohomology-with-compact-support) and the cited book by Michor seems to be what we need in order to establish the result. Strangely enough I couldn't find any reference which explicitly states that the compactly supported de Rham cohomology groups are isomorphic for homeomorphic manifolds.

To explicitly state my question: If the underlying topological spaces of two smooth manifolds (without boundary) $M$ and $N$ are homeomorphic, are their compactly supported de Rham cohomologies isomorphic?

Kind regards

Comment: Here's a reference that states what you asked about homeomorphic manifolds.  See Corollary 5.5 in chapter XI of *Éléments de Topologie Algebrique* by C. Godbillon.

Comment: Thank you! Such a reference was exactly what I was looking for. Out of curiosity, are you by any chance aware of any english publication where this result is stated?

Comment: I don't see it stated in either of the "obvious" places, Spivak's Differential Geometry or Bott/Tu. This is why mathematicians should have reading knowledge of French and German ;P